# How can I enable "Miracast over Infrastructure" for non-Surface Hub Windows 10 PCs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface, windows-networking

I was very excited to discover an article explaining how I can now use [Miracast over a Windows LAN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure). The technology is called *Miracast over Infrastructure*. For those unaware, Miracast is the protocol used by the Windows 10 ["Project to a second screen"](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/turn-windows-10-pc-into-wirelss-display) and "Projecting to this PC" functionality.

Only laptops (over wireless, with specific hardware), have had access to this feature up until now which is obviously quite frustrating when this functionality would be very useful over the LAN with regular workstations.

The problem is the article only seems to discuss this functionality in the context of the Surface Hub.

My questions:

- Is the Surface Hub running some custom software for this?
- Can that software be installed on a regular Windows 10, version 1703 PC ?
- What services need to be running to support *Miracast over Infrastructure*?

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for the same answer. Turns out that the answer is that you still need an active Wireless-adapter to establish the Miracast session.

Since this question was posted, the Microsoft documentation [linked in the question](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/miracast-over-infrastructure) has been updated with, among others, the following updates:

> On Windows 10 PCs, the **Projecting to this PC** feature must be enabled in System Settings, and the device must have a Wi-Fi interface enabled in order to respond to discovery requests that only occur through the Wi-Fi adapter.

Along with an FAQ-section that reads:

> **Why do I still need Wi-Fi to use Miracast over infrastructure?**
>
> Discovery requests to identify Miracast receivers can only occur
> through the Wi-Fi adapter. Once the receivers have been identified,
> Windows 10 can then attempt the connection to the network.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming Microsoft updated the article, because they now specifically mention Windows PC and Windows Phone alongside the Surface Hub in that article. Just make sure you're running version 1703 (or later) on both ends. 
As far as your specific scenario of miracasting between 2 "regular" Windows 10 1703 or above workstations is concerned, this portion of the article should help:

> A Surface Hub **or Windows PC** can act as a Miracast over
>   Infrastructure **receiver**. **A Windows PC or phone** can act as a
>   Miracast over Infrastructure **source**. As a Miracast **receiver**,
>   the Surface Hub **or device** must be connected to your enterprise
>   network **via either Ethernet** or a secure Wi-Fi connection (e.g.
>   using either WPA2-PSK or WPA2-Enterprise security). If the Surface Hub
>   or device is connected to an open Wi-Fi connection, Miracast over
>   Infrastructure will disable itself. As a Miracast **source**, the **Windows
>   PC or phone** must be connected to the same enterprise network via
>   **Ethernet** or a secure Wi-Fi connection.

Based on the Microsoft article and some Googling around to find real-world use cases, I can answer your questions as follows:

- No
- Not required
- I'm not sure what specific services 1703 updated/added, but the protocol is called "[[MS-MICE]: Miracast over Infrastructure Connection Establishment Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt796768.aspx)", and builds upon the following existing technologies:

> - Datagram Transport Layer Security (DTLS) [RFC6347]
> - Domain Name System (DNS) [IANA-DNS] [RFC1034] [RFC2181]
> - Multicast DNS (mDNS)[RFC6762]
> - Real-Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP) [RFC2326]
> - Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) [RFC793]
> - Wi-Fi Display Protocol [WF-DTS1.1]
> - Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer (P2P) Protocol [WF-P2P1.2]
> - Wi-Fi Simple Configuration (WSC) Protocol [WF-WSC2.0.2]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this question to own needs and here is my summary confirmed practically:

1. For initial connection - both 'projector' and 'remote display' - should be connected to same Wi-Fi network.
2. After connection is esteblished WiFi can be turned off. Connection keeps working via ethernet.
3. Important thing - name of the target 'remote display' should be resolvable via projector's DNS. Since PC simulenously connected to WiFi and Ethernet will have two IP addresses, client should make sure which IP remote name is actually resolved into. The easiest and most straighforward way to configure this - add entry into `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and then recheck via `ping REMOTE_DISPLAY_NAME`.
4. 'remote display' should have TCP port 7250 open in firewall

---

After all, my expectations that projecting via ethernet will be less laggy did not came true. Actually - I did not nothice any improvement. Result is pretty disappointing. Performance is acceptable for no more than text presentations with no animations.

Comment: For me the lag disappears when, in the Miracast toolbar that appears once a connection is established, you click the little gear and select 'games'. For 'work' and 'videos' the lag is so high as to be unworkable. It's very annoying you have to do this every time after establishing a connection, but it works for me. 

I have to say, overall this feature in Windows seems to be in a very crude state. If it doesn't work, you get 0 feedback why, and the dialog to set it up bugs out every now and then.